# Calling a Postgres stored Procedure using Spring + No value specified for parameter

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure defined in PostgresSql as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_points(accountId bigint, points numeric(19,5)) RETURNS void AS $$
...
...
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I call the following method to call the procedure:

```
public void updatePoints(final Account account, final BigDecimal points) {
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(coreJdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("update_points");
    SqlParameterSource inputs = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("accountId", account.getId())
        .addValue("points", points);                
    simpleCall.execute(inputs);
}
```

When the method is called, I get following spring error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{? = call update_points()}]; No value specified for parameter 1.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:190)
    at net.exchangesolutions.veo.dao.AccountTransactionDaoImpl.updateRewardsConsumedAmount(AccountTransactionDaoImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I tried another way to call the procedure with CallableStatement in which case the function is not called at all.
Do you know what is the problem with the code or have you any suggestion about how to call the procedure from SpringJPA?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is how I call with CallableStatement:

```
public void updatePoints(final Account account, final BigDecimal points) {
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = coreJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableSt = connection.prepareCall("{call update_points(?, ?)}");
            callableSt.setLong(1, account.getId());
            callableSt.setBigDecimal(2, points);        
            callableSt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using following method. I could not figure out why the two approaches above did not work. Anyway, following solution is working now.

```
public void updatePoints(final Account account,
            final BigDecimal points) {
        coreJdbcTemplate.execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con)
                    throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement cs = con
                        .prepareCall("{call update_points(?, ?)}");
                cs.setLong(1, account.getId());
                cs.setBigDecimal(2, points);
                return cs;
            }
        }, new CallableStatementCallback() {
            public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                    throws SQLException {
                cs.execute();

                return null;
            }
        });
```